An old horror movie where a young boy killed his parents
I am looking for an old movie. It is a movie where a young boy kills his family (I think his parents) and the story continues how he moved to the house where he lived when he was young and now another family lives there. And I think he started to work for them and after all he killed them.
I really do not know the year but I think it could be about 80s but I am not sure. It was a really long time ago when I saw it. I think that he even drew a pictures like his parents died. And he was living in a loft when he moved back to the house. And he was watching the family for some time like he was hiding and just after some time he started to work for them I think.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

What do you call "old"? I get depressed when people say "1990s"... because I consider "old" to be 1920s-40s... please  be more specific. Also, any additional details will be helpful

@Catija hey catija I really do not know the year but I think it could be about 80´ but I am not sure. It really long time ago when I saw it. I think that he even drew a pictures like his parents died.. And he was living in a loft when he moved back to the house.. And he was watching the family for some time like he was hiding and just after some time he started to work for them I think

Thanks for adding some more details. Feel free to stay on it and further work in everything else whenever you remember more and I'm sure we'll find a solution to it.

It sounds alot like the 1974 TV film Bad Ronald
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Ronald
Heres the trailer on youtube:



But in this film a young nerdy kid accidently kills a girl who taunts him.He tells his overprotective mother who fears his life will be ruined if hes caught so she converts a small room into a hiding place and keeps him secret telling the police that hes run off.
She keeps him hidden until one day she dies while out shopping, the boy stays hidden even when a new family buy the house and move in.He makes peepholes in the walls and spies on the new family and starts drawing fantasy pictures on the walls of his hideout.
Its a cult movie now and was written by SF author Jack Vance, its worth a watch.
